# ms access - data vanishes when i remove criteria and query the table

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access, vba

I want to select two records with an id of 1 and 2. Both appear via SQL query if I hard code it in the criteria column. However when I remove criteria and select the same data in SQL using a WHERE clause, only 1 record appears. What happened to the other record?  All filters are off.

**WORKS:**

**id**

```
Criteria: 1 or 2
```

**sql:**

```
select * from mytable where mytable.id=1 or mytable.id= 2 
 //2 records appear. Success.
```

**DOESNT WORK     <--but I need to code it this way.**

**id**

```
No Criteria:
```

**sql:**

```
select * from mytable where mytable.id=1 or mytable.id= 2  
//only record 1 appears. Failure.
```

Why is the 2nd record not appearing?

Comment: I can't make sense of your question...

Comment: they are exactly the same. top 1 produces 2 results, however the bottom one produces 1 result. my question is why? the only difference is i removed the criteria field from the table.

Comment: Are you actually trying to `SELECT '` from the table? Or did you perhaps mean `SELECT *`?

Comment: sorry yes. select *. typo in the form.

Comment: It doesn't seem you have removed anything. The two queries are identical.

Comment: If you use access, you know that in design mode, you can set a columns criteria. I set my ids criteria to 1 or 2. If I use the same select statement, 2 records are returned. However if I remove criteria from design mode, and run the SAME select statement in SQL only 1 record is displayed. Do you see the difference now?

Comment: Do you mean, that if you remove second criteria `or id=2` and you leave only: `id=1`, then only 1 record is returned? This is expected.

Comment: @ypercube - From my reading, the `criteria` the OP is refering to is part of the graphical Access environment.  The OP is not talking about changes to the SQL statement directly, but rather changes made in the graphical environment.  Unfortunately I haven't touched Access in 8 years, so I haven't a clue, but I'm pretty certain this is an Access question, and not a "SQL Basics" question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is when you build a query using the query builder as you point out a simple condition such as this works just fine:

```
1 or 2
```

So if you type above into query builder, you see this and it does work:

[image]

However, if you flip into SQL view, you will see that Access actually writes out that you MUST include the column name.

[image]

Eg you need this:

```
[id] = 1 or [id] = 2
```

So you have to include the column name. And if you flip the query builder into SQL view mode, you will see access wrote this for you:

So, for such conditions you write by hand, or in code, you need to include the column name. You also I suppose could write this:

```
[id] in (1,2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but when I add the table name I still have the same issue. Actually sql only finds the first ID in the table each time. BTW I am pulling data from a multi-joined query that I saved in access as a table query. Could that be the problem?